# Get Current Page Url In Adobe CQ5 for Canonical Link

Tags: seo, aem, canonical-link

Is there a standard way in Adobe CQ5 to get the current page url in order to create automatic canonical links in the head of the JSP?

Basically we have a dialogue config box where you can override the canonical link, but by default if this is empty I want to construct the link based on the raw URL path for the current request.

The JSP for the head is shared across all requests.

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `${currentPage.path}` variable will give you the path of the parent page to the current resource, but you should use the Externalizer to make this into a nice user-facing URL, (i.e. applying any mapping rules that you have in place & using the correct domain name, rather than the server name e.g. `prod-server-123`)

i.e.

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
Externalizer externalizer = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Externalizer.class);
String canonicalUrl = externalizer.publishLink(resourceResolver, "http", currentPage.getPath());
```

You can customise what the externalizer treats as the base URL via [Felix](http://local.host:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.commons.impl.ExternalizerImpl), or via an `osgi:Config` node in your repository. and read more on the official [docs on the Adobe site](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/externalizer.html).

(Note that the Externalizer is CQ5.5+)

Comment: So, forgive my noobness with CQ, but currentPage and/or request variables are passed where? How do I get the request in my model? Its not injected in to the constructor. And in head.jsp I have a page object, but it doesnt seem to have the path property?

Comment: If you're working with JSPs, you use the `cq:defineObjects` tag, which should make `currentPage` available in the request. If you're working in a Java servlet, you can extend from `SlingAllMethodsServlet`, to get access to the SlingRequest from which you can get the current resource. I'm not sure what you mean that it's not injected into the constructor — do you have any sample code that you could show? If you expand your question, I can expand my answer :) Might be difficult to do through comments otherwise!

Comment: You were a great deal of help in finally solving it! The currentPage variable did exist, and I just had to namespace the Externalizer to get it to work correctly.

All is well now! Many thanks again

Comment: Cool, no problem — glad you got it sorted :)